# Why doen't this send pattern match?

Tags: rubocop, ruby-parser

I have written a custom rubocop cop, the excerpts are like this:

```rb
def_node_matcher :is_foo_bar?, <<-PATTERN
  (send (const nil :Foo) :bar)
PATTERN

def on_send(node)
  puts "Match" if is_foo_bar?(node)
end
```

I'm trying the cop on the following code:

```rb
Foo.bar
```

Interestingly enough, `node.to_s` says the following, which exactly matches my pattern:

```
"(send
  (const nil :Foo) :bar)"
```

But the node does not match. If I change the pattern to the following, it works though:

```
(send (...) :bar)
```

Why doesn't my original match work?

My versions:

- ruby 2.6.2
- ast 2.4.0
- rubocop 0.77.0
- parser 2.6.4.1

Answer (score 5):

Some time back, we changed the matcher for `nil` to be `nil?`. This has the unfortunate side-effect that you can no longer copy-paste output from `ruby-parse` or `node.to_s` and instantly have a working matcher.

Just adding the additional question mark should make your pattern work again:

```
def_node_matcher :is_foo_bar?, <<-PATTERN
  (send (const nil? :Foo) :bar)
PATTERN
```